# Что то не так с гамбургером

Tags: javascript, jquery

Дело такое, при нажатии на гамбургер , он анимирует и открывается меню, тут все норм.
Но после того как нажал на пустое место(не на меню) , меню закрывается НО бургер не меняется в обратное состояние, почему, подскажите?

[При нажатии на гамбургер](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alh3X.png) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alh3X.png)

[При нажатии на пустое место](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMKOF.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMKOF.png)

[При повторном нажатии на гамбургер](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptv6g.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptv6g.png)

вот код:

```js
$('#my-menu').click(function(e) {
  var $menuy = $('#menuy');

  if ($menuy.css('display') != 'block') {
    $menuy.show();

    var firstClick = true;
    $(document).bind('click.myEvent', function(e) {
      if (!firstClick && $(e.target).closest('#menuy').length == 0) {
        $menuy.hide();
        $(document).unbind('click.myEvent');
      }
      firstClick = false;
    });
  }

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, разобрался.